# How do I print these vertical problems, horizontally?

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing, helper

I'm trying to make horizontal problems vertical, then print those vertical problems horizontally. If that makes sense...

I tried doing the `for i in (list): print(I, end = " ")` but that just makes it come out like stairs. I expected it to come out horizontal.

Here's what I have for now:

```py
problems = \["57 + 8", "33 - 145", "11 - 6"\]
def aaaa(y):
    altprobs = []
    das = "-"
    first = " "
    second = " "
    for piece in y:
        fn = piece.split(" ")[0]
        op = piece.split(" ")[1]
        sn = piece.split(" ")[2]
        leng = max(len(fn), len(sn))
        if leng == len(sn):
            leng = leng + 2
            first = fn.rjust(leng)
            string = first+"\n"+op+" "+sn+"\n"+das*leng
        elif leng == len(fn):
            leng = leng + 2
            first = fn.rjust(leng)
            second = op+" "+sn.rjust(leng-2)
            string = first+"\n"+second+"\n"+das*leng
        print(string)
print(aaaa(problems))
```